# Just updated ImageResizer via NuGet, can't run app because it can't find BundleAttribute

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, imageresizer

I was just trying to update Azure Storage, but doing that meant I needed to update the ImageResizer AzureReader and update the app to use .Net 4.5.2 (the Azure site is set for .Net 4.6). Now I've got everything at the newest version; I've cleaned and rebuilt the app. It works fine locally, but when I publish it to Azure, I get the following error. I can not get the diagnostics page to load.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +403
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +20
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +315
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +188
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +1184
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +146
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +180
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +184
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +138
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +38
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +242
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +108
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +642
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +353
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +447

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +684
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +121
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +771
```

All of my ImageResizer plugins are at version 4.0.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing v3 ImageResizer assemblies with v4 ImageResizer assemblies. Remove all ImageResizer* dll files and re-install exactly one version.

Comment: This is basically, the right answer. It turned out that when I was publishing to Azure, it was retaining the old dll files. I had to tell VS that I wanted it to remove all the files in the deployment slot before publishing.

Answer (score 1):

maybe some of your other dependency is depending on ImageResizer 4.0.0.0

you can use assembly redirection as work-around

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
          culture="en-us" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get the same error. I can't think of anything other than an ImageResizer plugin that would be dependent on it. I'm very new to C# development, though. 

So, I'm looking through the solution, and I see that, while I've upgraded my one assembly to ImageResizer 4.0.4, the solution has a NuGet dependency on ImageResizer 3.4.3. Could that be causing the trouble? I really hope I don't have to upgrade every single assembly in this solution.

Comment: @BunsofAluminum so ImageResizer 4.0.4 is not NuGet reference? if so, removed this and try to update the one that manage by NuGet. this way is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the severity of your wrong versioning by enabling the `File Version` column in Explorer and looking in your `/bin` folder.

As you can see I have 4.2 for the main DLL but 3.4 for other DLLs.

[image]