# System.TypeLoadException: "ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute"

Tags: imageresizer

I try migration ImageResizer v3 to v4. After upgrade I can not call ImageResizer and not even support page. Support page error is:

```
[TypeLoadException: Der Typ "ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute" in der Assembly "ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" konnte nicht geladen werden.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +191
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +162
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +148
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +604
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +144
   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) +111
   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) +17
   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element) +60
   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DiagnosticPageHandler.GenerateOutput(HttpContext context, Config c) +943
   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DiagnosticPageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +904
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +98
```

How can I fix that? I uninstalled modules and reinstalled but with no luck:

```
ImageResizer.4.0.5
ImageResizer.Plugins.TinyCache.4.0.5
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279041/just-updated-imageresizer-via-nuget-cant-run-app-because-it-cant-find-bundlea

Answer (score 0):

You have left in 1 or more plugins from ImageResizer v3. You can't use a a v3 plugin with v4 ImageResizer.dll.

Comment: I have checked that more than one time and rebuild the project several times. As far as I can say this problem occurs only when I install TinyCache 4.0.5 plugin, without ImageResizer 4.0.5 will work.

Comment: Can you share the full list of .dlls in your /bin folder? Only ImageResizer plugins from V3 would reference ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute; it's no longer used in v4.